# Setting Up Callback url in node API

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing

How can I set up a callback URL in node?
For example, lets say I'm creating a e-commerce site. If the user is not logged in before purchasing, i need to redirect the `example.com/buy` to `example.com/login` and once they finish login I want to redirect them to `example.com/buy` page. How can i implement it?

Thank you

Comment: I have searched a lot for it and i dont think i need to put up the messy code here, i just wanted to know how to do it...! thanks anyway -----

Answer (score 2):

Add their current url to the querystring when redirecting to the login page (`example.com/login?redirect=/buy`) and use that query to redirect them back to their previous page after login.

Comment: `localhost:3500/api/products/men?redirect=https://google.com` I have tested it like this, but browser does not redirect me to google.com

Comment: @abh_01 It doesn't happen automatically... you have to actually check for the parameter and redirect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the actual way you're going to implement this. The crucial point is when the login form is processed; after the user has logged in successfully, you want to send them to `/`, but if they tried to buy something, you want to send them to `/buy`. So how can you store the previous intent so it can be read by the server at the time of the redirect?

One easy choice is adding a GET parameter to the URL. Instead of sending them to `/login`, you send them to `/login?redirect=buy`. Then you use a `<form>` without `action`, which will retain the URL for node to process. Once the login checks out, you simply check if there's a `redirect` param and act accordingly.

Another way is to store the user's intent in a `session` parameter and read that back at the appropriate time.

The question really becomes "How do I store information for a user that survives navigating to a new page, and which I can read on the server at any time?" Once you remove the specific use case from the more general problem, it's easier to find existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

You have to handle this in the front-end (Angular/react/Vue) technology using token/cookies and then re-route user to appropriate page or URL regarding it

For how to handle routing in front-end [Reference](https://medium.com/planet-arkency/one-router-to-route-them-all-or-finding-the-best-routing-766764802f70)

If you are using Server-side rendering then try [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) or [EJS](http://ejs.co/)

Comment: This doesn't have to be handled in the front-end at all. Sessions and cookies can be set on the client via the server code. So I don't think tell them to use Angular/react/vue is an ideal solution seen as those aren't tagged in the question

Comment: There is no suggestion, whatsoever, in the question that the OP is writing a SPA.